# CSS Framework for UI Development

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks, air, css-frameworks

I'm making an app in Adobe Air and I want to make a robust looking UI. And it's quite hard to do in CSS, I just end up with lots of messy code that probably doesn't work that well anyway.

So does anyone know of a good UI CSS framework that focuses on a robust layout rather than pointless slidy [crap](http://jqueryui.com/) and datepickers.

Comment: Do you need a JavaScript framework like Qooxdoo or YUI or a CSS framework?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Blueprint css framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) with BOKS

First you need to understand how Blueprint works

which u can found here  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/a-closer-look-at-the-blueprint-css-framework/

then use [BOKS](https://toki-woki.net/p/Boks/help.php)

http://toki-woki.net/p/Boks/help.html

> Boks is an AIR application (so it
>   works on Windows, Mac and Linux) that
>   provides a User Interface for
>   Blueprint CSS's framework. It's been
>   designed for those who think the Grid
>   System is good but never really took
>   the time to give it love.
>
> It handles grid configuration,
>   baseline rhythm pimpin', CSS (with or
>   without compression) and grid.png
>   export, HTML layout and much more
>   goodie-goodie!

[image]
<sub>(source: [toki-woki.net](http://toki-woki.net/p/Boks/screen/main.jpg))</sub>

[Photoshop Template for Blueprint CSS Comp](https://web.archive.org/web/20130613071702/http://urlgreyhot.com/personal/resources/photoshop_template_blueprint_css_comps)

Comment: blueprint is crap with mobile

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript frameworks with good UI widgets:

- [qooxdoo](http://www.qooxdoo.org)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

CSS frameworks:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/09/21/css-frameworks-css-reset-design-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0):

[960.gs](http://960.gs/) is a decent CSS framework for layout. Though personally I normally roll my own, taking snippets from my previous work and build it up. Using standards mode means virtually no variation between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/) :

- **Flexibility:** You won't find any framework that has a more flexible grid system or better browser support. Its panel, tab block, table and navigation components also provide unprecedented flexibility.
- **Lightweight:** If you use only Cascade Framework's core features, you'll need to include only 8.5 kb (2.6 kb gzipped) of framework CSS code. If you want everything, including all Fontawesome icons, you'll need to include 51.9 kb (10.8 kb gzipped) of framework CSS code. If that's still too much, there's also a fatfree minimal version called [**Cascade Framework Light**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframeworklight/).
- **Cross-Browser Compatible:** Cascade Framework allows you to create a responsive layout in all modern browsers. In IE6-8, you'll serve the desktop version of your website.
- **Modular:** Cascade Framework provides you with several individual modules as well as a couple of builds (combining individual modules).